# Data Interpretation Problem from GRE

Tags: statistics

This is problem from GRE Quant.

[image]

And here is the question:
[image]

From definition below graph we have: $\text{Stress Factor} = \dfrac{\text{Diff. Factor}}{\text{Average Time(per question)}}$.

We see that if *Difficulty Factor* insreases then *Stress Factor* also increases. So the answer is (C). Am I right?

If my answer is incorrect please show me the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation only holds if average time per question is constant. As you can see from the table, it varies. You'll need to actually compute the difficulty factor and stress factor for each of the 5 years and sort the data to see how the three columns (difficulty, stress, cutoff) correlate.

It turns out that (III) is false, since $1994$ had a higher Difficulty Factor than $1991$ ($278$ versus $200$), yet a lower Stress Factor ($\approx 3.9$ versus $\approx 4.2$).